# Coordinate free optimization of an integral

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, optimization, vector-analysis, area

I was trying to solve this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230865/find-the-value-of-x-0-at-which-the-area-of-the-pedal-curve-of-the-ellipse-with?noredirect=1&lq=1) using vectors and ideas of gradient, all the context is same as original except the fact that point lines on the x-axis. I want here the point to lie anywhere on the plane.

> Find the value of  x0  at which the area of the pedal curve of the ellipse with respect to the point P( x0 , 0) is minimized

---

#### My attempt:

Let the tangent line be represented as $\tau$ and let the signed  distance from tangent line to point be $d_{\tau}(p)$, finally let the unit normal vector of the tangent line be $n$.

Note that $p$ is given as an ordered pair of coordinates, in whatever coordinate system you use. Now, the [foot of perpendicular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/foot-of-perpendicular-to-line) is given as:

$$f_{\tau} (p) = p-d_{\tau} (p) n$$

Now, we can parameterize the unit normal as a function of  $t$

$$ F_{\tau} (p,t) = f_{\tau} (p) = p - d_{\tau} \left( p\right) n(t)$$

Now, we want the area of Pedal curve, we can use the gauss shoelace formula for this, treating $F_{\tau}(t)$ as a position vector:

$$\begin{align} \int F_{\tau} (t,p)  \times \frac{d}{dt} F_{\tau} (t,p)  dt  = \int  \left[ p - d_{\tau}(p) n\right] \times \left[-d_{\tau}(p) \frac{dn}{dt}-\frac{d (d_{\tau}(p) )}{dt} n\right] dt=\\ \int \left[ d_{\tau}(p) \frac{dn}{dt}+n \frac{d (d_{\tau}(p) )}{dt} \right]\times \left[ p-d_{\tau}(p)n\right] dt= \int \frac{dn}{dt} \times \left[ p d_{\tau}(p)- (d_{\tau} (p))^2 n \right] + \frac{d (d_{\tau}(p) )}{dt}n \times \left[ p\right]dt \end{align}$$

The final problem is to find a point $p$ such that the integral:

$$I(p) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dn}{dt} \times \left[ p d_{\tau} (p) - d_{\tau}(p)^2 n \right] + \frac{d (d_{\tau}(p) )}{dt}n \times \left[ p\right] dt$$

Is minimized.

Brute forcing by taking the parameterization $(a \cos \theta, b \sin \theta)$ of ellipse and the normals and $\frac{dn}{dt}$ calculations became literal hell.

I thought perhaps we could use the idea of the gradient and see where that vanishes to find max i.e: find where point $p$ such that:

$$ \nabla I(p) = 0$$

However, I am not sure how to compute the gradient of the integral in this case. Some help would be appreciated.

**p.s: Ideally speaking I'd like to finish the proof completely with 0 use of coordinates.**

---

1/8/2022: We can make a simplification for the integral:

$$G(p)= \oint \frac{dn}{dt} \times \left[ p d_{\tau} (p) - d_{\tau}(p)^2 n \right] dt \int_{0}^{2\pi} (\frac{dn}{dt} \times n) \left[ p_n d_{\tau} (p) - d_{\tau}(p)^2 \right] dt$$

Due to the fact that $ \frac{dn}{dt} \times p = \frac{dn}{dt} \times n d_{\tau}(p)$ where $d_{\tau}(p)$ is the component of $p$ along $n$ (i.e: vector of p to foot of perpendicular), hence $G(p)$ is zero everywhere.

Hence,

$$I(p)= \oint  \frac{d (d_{\tau}(p) )}{dt}n \times \left[ p\right] dt$$

I suppose, I would have to nudge the above expression in some direction $ dp $ and check the first order variation:

$$I(p+ dp)= \oint n\frac{d}{dt} \left[ d_{\tau}(p) + \nabla d_{\tau}(p)  \cdot dp \right] \times \left[ p+   dp\right]dt$$

Not sure how to continue..
$$ dI = \oint \left[ n \frac{d(d_{\tau} (p))}{dt} \times dp + n \left[ \frac{d}{dt}  \nabla d_{\tau}(p)  \cdot dp \right] \times p\right] +O(|dp|^2)dt$$

To repeat: The goal is to find what $p$ is

Comment: which question are you trying to solve? Your first link is to a youtube video

Comment: Bruh moment. I messed up the links. Now it's fixed. Thank you @peek-a-boo

Comment: also, isn't the question already solved there?

Comment: you are correct, it is solved there. I am trying to figure out how to do this with the gradient. @peek-a-boo also my point $p$ can be anywhere in the plane.